# Графический интерфейс в Java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! Я занимаюсь изучением джава и меня интересует вопрос, связанный с приложениями. Сейчас, конечно же, пишу всё самое простое. И у меня вопрос: Как скоро я смогу перейти к разработке неконсольных приложений? Чтоб они читались на телефоне или на каком-либо эмуляторе. Могу ли я начинать уже сейчас? Или лучше обучиться большему? Есть, например Sony Ericsson w810i и HTC Wildfire. Про андроид наверное спрашивать не буду, так как вроде там сложновато. А вот на обычную соньку?

Comment: Андроид - не сложновато: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учите основы, а паралельно можете и для телефонов писать, а то могут возникнуть некие пробелы и всё равно придётся возвращаться назад и доучивать...

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не кодил для телефонов, но думаю стоит начать с загрузки `j2me` и "хелло ворлд" для телефонов. Java везде одна и таже, разное только количество (набор) пакетов. Также, загрузите javadoc, чтоб иметь информацию о доступных классах.

Comment: Спасибо, а могу ли я начинать на очень низком уровне? Получится ли?

Comment: Найдите примитивное GUI приложение на Swing и для телефона. Не думаю, что они сильно будут отличатся по сложности. 
 
Ну синтаксис один и тот же. Выберите которое вам понятнее, с него и начните. 

Набор классов и пакетов (ну и набор функционала) в j2me сильно ограничен, поэтому выучить большинство из них будет проще. с другой стороны, скорее за все, что большинство примеров в инете для телефонов ориентированы на более опытных.

Опять же, это легко проверить экспериментально (см. начало комментария)

Answer (score 0):

С подходом смогу не смогу не стоит учить вобще ничего. Главные критерии должны быть "есть желания" или "нет желания" все остальное мелочи

Comment: А тут нету вопроса "смогу или не смогу?". Есть вопрос "Смогу ли со своими примитивными знаниями". Раз уж начал, значит желание есть :)

Comment: Правда, что ты разнылся: смогу, не смогу... Возьми и сделай. Не хватит знаний - учись.

Comment: @mikillskegg ты, видать, не знаешь как люди ноют. В любом случае помимо "ненужного текста" здесь есть вопрос. А вот твоей оценки моих вопросов мне не надо...

Comment: Если тебе не нужно оценки моих вопросов, то иди на форумы, где меня нет. А здесь любой участник может оценить любой вопрос.

Только вопроса я и не увидел. Откуда кто-то может знать что ты можешь, а что нет? Если хочешь узнать - попробуй сам. Возьми книги, руководства и т.д. и попробуй. Возникнет какой-то конкретный вопрос - задавай на здоровье. А так...

Comment: Мне не нужна оценка моих действий, если быть точнее. Спасибо за ответ. Дальнейшее обсуждение считаю бесцельным.

Comment: Счастья и успеха

Comment: Вообще мне кажется, что то, что я пытаюсь убедиться в выборе своего пути - не негативное действие. То, что я прошу помощи у людей, которые с этим знакомы - тоже вроде бы не плохое действие. Не понимаю, зачем писать здесь, что я ною, если я просто пытаюсь здраво оценить свои возможности?

Comment: Если тебя очень мучает вопрос, сможешь ли ты с самыми элементарными знания в Джаве писать GUI, то получи ответ: надо еще немного поучиться. Если все же тебя еще этот вопрос мучает, возьми книжку по Swing и почитай. Если все пойдет гладко, значит так и двигайся. 

Насчет выбора жизненного пути вообще спрашивать кого-то не надо. Ты должен понять это сам. И еще совет от старого человека: поменьше самокопания, побольше работы.

Comment: Не думать сможеш или нет не оценивать знания как примитивные. Документацию в зубы и пробовать пробовать пробовать. c awt на java можно с 0% разобраться за месяц до состояния сделать приложение с gui (правда до этого был опыт в более других языках)